# What does these long wicks mean in a candle stick chart?

Tags: stock-analysis

What are the *long low wicks* mean in the following chart? They are highlighted in yellow.

The volume stat for the highlighted middle one is given below:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A long wick means that the high/low range for the time period was large.

The middle one which is very long could have been caused by:

- A fat fingered trade made at the low of the range
- Normal trading throughout the range
- Bad data from the provider

What actually occurred could be determined by looking at Time & Sales.

Comment: I added the volume stat to the original post. It says 139.16K.